# PDF created with FPDF cannot be opened by Adobe Reader

Tags: php, pdf, adobe, fpdf

My PDF file cannot be opened with Adobe Reader. What's weird is that the PDF used to work in Adobe Reader just a few days ago and now it does not work, and of course I didn't modify the code otherwise it would be easy to fix.

I validated my PDF and learned it was a PDF/A-3, could be that it is not a PDF/A-1? If so why did it work for a time and suddenly stopped working?

**EDIT**

The problem was that somehow, some HTML code was output inside the PDF file, thus making the PDF file invalid for Adobe Reader, but not for Firefox, making all this much more confusing than it should be.

So a tip to anyway having trouble with PDF, open it with a text editor such as Notepad++ for Windows or GEdit for Linux, and compare with another PDF file which works fine. You should find the problem pretty quickly.

Comment: You have a PDF file that working in Acrobat reader a few days ago and now it doesn't? If the PDF file hasn't changed, then the culprit might be Acrobat. Has Adobe pushed an update in the last couple of days?

Comment: It is not the same PDF file, its a new PDF file generated from the same code. The old PDF files still works.

Comment: Is it the same data? The key here is to make sure you're comparing apples to apples: generate a **new** PDF from the exact same data as the old PDF. If the new PDF doesn't work **and** it contains the  same data as the old PDF, then you can start to examine the differences between the two files. If they're not the same data, then you have no way of knowing if the problem is due to something in the file format or if FPDF generated a malformed PDF file due to something in the data.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did, it did have the same data, however it also had some HTML code, which should be there. I removed manualy the HTML code to very if it was the source of the problem (even though it is a problem, it could not be the source of my problem) and it fixed it. So I just have some echo'ed HTML somewhere when it shouldn't.

Comment: Interesting... sounds like it might be a bug in FPDF.

Comment: Try TCPDF from www.tcpdf.org/‎

Comment: or open the PDF file on another computer.

Comment: please put the solution into an actual answer ( instead of an edit of the question) and accept it as soon as you are allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

I read a lot of questions about this and I understood that the problem is happening with:

```
ob_start();
```

Without this line, my FPDF was not working with the message explained that there was another buffer first.
With this line, the PDF was readable only with Browser.

I changed this line to:

```
ob_clean();
```

and now I can open PDF with any reader.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me, too. It did work in Firefox for me, but not in Chrome and it wouldn't open in Adobe.

The problem was that I was trying to run the script in a function and calling the function from a button. I fixed it simply by adding the script to it's own PHP file, and then linking to the php file directly.

Note: I did try `ob_start()` (and alternatively `ob_clean()` as noted in the other answer) and `ob_end_flush()`, but it didn't make a difference in the function. When it's in its own file it doesn't need it anyway.

```php
// file.php
<?php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/plugins/eri-webtools-plugin/libraries/fpdf/fpdf.php'; // <-- File path for WordPress plugin
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output(); // To Download, use $pdf->Output('D', 'test.pdf', true);
?>

// html
<a href="file.php">View PDF</a>
```