# FPDF pdf file opening

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

"Adobe Reader could not open beacuse it is either not a supported file type"

Php Fpdf file has generate but it not opening via Adobe Reader but opening via browser and other pdf reader, any idea?

```html
function viewfortressmonthly($datese, $location_idnew) {
   
        $companyid = $_SESSION['companyid'];
        $pieces = explode("-", $location_idnew);
        $location_id = $pieces[0];
        $site_id = $pieces[1];
        $this->selectLocationFromSite($companyid, $site_id, $location_id);
        $monthnumber = substr($datese, 2, 2);
        $monthname = date('F', strtotime("2000-$monthnumber-01"));

        if (substr($datese, 2, 2) == "01" || substr($datese, 2, 2) == "03" || substr($datese, 2, 2) == "05" || substr($datese, 2, 2) == "07" || substr($datese, 2, 2) == "08" || substr($datese, 2, 2) == "10" || substr($datese, 2, 2) == "12") {
            $array_day = array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31");
        } else if (substr($datese, 2, 2) == "04" || substr($datese, 2, 2) == "06" || substr($datese, 2, 2) == "09" || substr($datese, 2, 2) == "11") {
            $array_day = array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30");
        } else {
            $array_day = array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29");
        }
        $array_time = array('00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23');
        $conn = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $this->dbName) or die('error connect');
       
        $pdf = new PDF("L", "in", "A4");
        $pdf->SetMargins(.1, .05, .05);
        $pdf->AddFont('gothic', '', 'gothic.php');
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
        $pdf->AddFont('UNIVERS0_0', '', 'UNIVERS0_0.php');
        $pdf->SetFont('UNIVERS0_0', 'U', 18);
        $pdf->SetFont('gothic', '', 16);
        $pdf->Cell(7.7, .30, 'PATROL RECORDS-' . "20" . substr($datese, 0, 2) . "-" . substr($datese, 2, 2) . "[" . $monthname . "]", 0, 2, "C", 1);
        $pdf->Cell(7.7, .30, $this->location, 0, 2, "C", 1);
        $pdf->SetFont('gothic', '', 10);
        $pdf->Cell(.36, .25, "D/H", 'LTRB', 0, "C", 1);
        foreach ($array_day as $days) {
            $pdf->Cell(.36, .25, $days, 'LTRB', 0, "C", 1);
        }
        $pdf->Ln();
        $pdf->SetFont('gothic', '', 6);
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array_time); $i++) {
            $pdf->Cell(.36, .25, $array_time[$i], 'LTRB', 0, "C", 1);
            foreach ($array_day as $days) {
                $datefinal = $datese . $days . $array_time[$i];
                $query2 = "select DATETIME from $this->dbName.$this->dbViewTable where DATETIME LIKE '$datefinal%' AND  COMPANY_ID='$companyid' AND SITE_ID='$site_id' AND LOCATION_ID='$location_id' order by ID DESC LIMIT 1";
                $result = $conn->query($query2);
                $row2 = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $date = $row2['DATETIME'];
                $timec = substr($date, 6, 2) . ":" . substr($date, 8, 2) . ":" . substr($date, 10, 2);
                if ($timec == "::") {
                    $imagefill = "images/colors/bg.png";
                    $pdf->Cell(.36, .25, "" . $pdf->Image($imagefill, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), .36, .25), 'LTBR', 0, 'C');
                } else {
                    $pdf->Cell(.36, .25, $timec, 'LTRB', 0, "C", 1);
                }
            }
            $pdf->Ln();
        }
        ob_clean();
        $pdf->Output("Reports-$location_id-$datese.pdf", 'D');
        $conn->close();
    }
```

can any one help resolve this problem

Comment: Please post any relevant code that might help us troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/22817210/1740715

Answer (score 0):

I putted this to fix this problem in the beggining (ob_clean) doesn't change PDF structure:

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
ob_clean();
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.